# Pygame delay argument

Tags: python, pygame, arguments, delay

```
desired_fps=int(60)
my_delay=1/desired_fps
pygame.time.delay(my_delay)
```

Error - Delay require one integer argument.
When work fine:

```
pygame.time.delay(60)
```

Why?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking about. But, `1/desired_fps` gives a floating point number. The parameter to [`pygame.time.delay()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay) has to be integral and its unit is milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for help! my_delay=int(1000/desired_fps) now in works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1/desired_fps` gives a floating point number. The parameter to [`pygame.time.delay()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay) has to be integral and its unit is milliseconds.
Since 1 second are 1000 milliseconds, it has to be:

```py
my_delay = int(1000/desired_fps)
pygame.time.delay(my_delay)
```

respectively

```py
my_delay = 1000 // desired_fps
pygame.time.delay(my_delay)
```

Note, `//` is the floor division operator. See [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).